# Slow internet data download using single connection, but fast using multiple

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I recently moved in to a new apartment and the house owner is providing the internet.
He has 16 Mbps connection from his ISP (Deutsche Telekom). I am only able to connect to his infrastructure via wireless.

Whenever I am downloading any data from the internet, for example watching streamed video or downloading a file, the connection is very slow. Only about 50-100 KB/s.

But, if I am using some special software, like jDownloader or BitTorrent, which is set to get the source file with multiple connections, the download speed increases and often even reaches the limit of 16 Mbps.

For example, downloading latest NetBeans installer file, I get around 50 KB/s using Firefox (1 connection) and 500 KB/s or more using jDownloader (10 connections).

What could be the cause of this slow single connections?

Running a speed test on http://www.speedtest.net/ reports around 5.41 Mbps download and 0.90 Mbps upload with ping of 23.

I can imagine that the ISP is reducing the speed for single connections. I doubt that the house owner has any technical knowledge to reduce the connection speed and the used router is a simple router from the ISP with original Software (as far as I could tell from getting to it's login page).

I've tested this with multiple PCs and OS - there is no difference.

Comment: Could it be the website you are downloading from that is limiting the bandwidth?

Comment: @SaintWacko It is slow on every site I go to. Rarely it goes to about 250 KB/s but never more than that. At least not for single connections. Multiple are always much faster.

Comment: Is it the same slow speed for every website, or does the speed change depending on what website you're on?

Comment: Have you asked the building owner (_your_ ISP) what's up with it?  Maybe he has (or hired someone) to implement some kind of traffic shaping (QoS)?  I'm not sure what we can help you with if you don't have access or control over the infrastructure.

Comment: @SaintWacko the speed does change on different websites, but it is never higher than 250 KB/s and using multiple connection always speeds it up.

Comment: @rbx That kinda sounds like it's the website limiting your bandwidth. That would also explain why multiple connections speed it up. Have you tried downloading from the same site on a different network/ISP to see if you get the same effect?

Comment: @techie007 I did not ask him yet, because I know he has no idea how to do it himself. But you're right, he could have hired someone to do it, I will ask him once he is back from vacation...

Comment: @SaintWacko downloading from the same sites from my old place or from university is much faster. So that's not it. Anyway it is not just one or ten websites. It is every page I visit.

Comment: @rbx Alright, well, it was worth a shot.